# Silverlight as a desktop app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, silverlight

This might sound daft but how do you get silverlight to run as a desktop application? Or should I just use WPF? Is there anything silverlight will bring that WPF wont? From a design and practical coding point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends upon what you mean -- do you mean that you want an internet-delivered app, but that you don't want it to have to be in the browser?  If so, then you could use Silverlight with out of browser.

Do you mean that you really want something more like a thick client -- like a traditional exe?  If so, you will not get much use out of Silverlight.  Silverlight is expects to be a distributed app, so it lacks some things that you would expect to have in a desktop app.

Examples:

- There is no Ado.net for Silverlight (no way to query a table directly -- it expects that you will use web services to retrieve data) (no entity framework for Silverlight either)
- Silverlight apps expect to run in partial trust -- you have to do some extra work to get Out Of Browser to run in full trust, and since it runs in partial trust by default, you get no file system access.  (which is fine for a web app, where your data processing is occuring as a result of service calls)

The Silverlight runtime is a separate animal from the .Net runtime.  For the most part, Silverlight is a subset of .net (there are some differences, particularly in XAML features), so you are using a different runtime when you run silverlight.  (so upcoming .net 4.5 features won't be supported in Silverlight, for example).

All that said, Silverlight is a really nice solution for an internet/intranet multi-tier application, it's just that the app MUST be multi-tier.

Comment: Ahhh!! Very nice answer. Im really not sure what I want atm I have to follow soa prinicples and its more of a cloud based service oirentated design i want to attempt. The first part you mentioned is more what im attempting, internet-delivered app, but that I don't want it to have to be in the browser. What I really want is everything to be delivered from the server over the net. Im just not sure where or how to start it.

Comment: For what it's worth, we are building a large application right now that sounds about like what you describe.  We are using Silverlight on the front end (with an MVVM architecture -- using Prism to help with that), we are using WCF RIA Services to move data, and we are using Entity Framework with POCO's on the back end.  It's been a very productive environment.

Comment: For a lot more info, search for the Firestarter silverlight videos -- there is some really good stuff there, it helped us out a lot when we were getting started.

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight will just bring a lot of limitations...

But still the latest versions do support "Silverlight out of Browser" and "Silverlight full trust"

What you gain is a code-base that could still run on the Web (with some adaptations).

Comment: I did not know there was a SilverLight out of Browser.  +1   I would still go WPF if I had a choice.